# Regular Expression (Java) anomaly - explanation sought

Tags: java, regex

Using Java (1.6) I want to split an input string that has components of a header, then a number of tokens.  Tokens  conform to this format: a ! char, a space char, then a 2 char token name (from constrained list e.g. C0 or 04) and then 5 digits.  I have built a pattern for this, but it fails for one token (CE) unless I remove the requirement for the 5 digits after the token name.  Unit test explains this better than I could (see below)

Can anyone help with what's going on with my failing pattern? The input CE token looks OK to me...

Cheers!

```
@Test
public void testInputSplitAnomaly() {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(! [04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE]\\d{5}))");
    splitByRegExp(pattern);
}
@Test
public void testInputSplitWorks() {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?=(! [04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE]))");
    splitByRegExp(pattern);
}


public void splitByRegExp(Pattern pattern) {
    String input = "& 0000800429! C600080 123456789-! C000026 213  00300! 0400020 A1Y1! Q200002 13! CE00202 01 ! Q600006 020507! C400012 O00511011";
    String[] tokens = pattern.split(input);
    Arrays.sort(tokens);
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
    for (String token : tokens) {
        System.out.println(token.substring(0,11));
    }
    assertThat(tokens,Matchers.hasItemInArray(startsWith("! CE")));
    assertThat(tokens.length,is(8));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your mistake here is your use of square brackets. Don't forget that these indicate a character class, so `[04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE]` doesn't do what you expect it to.

What it *does* do is the following:

- `[04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]` constitutes a character class, matching one of: `|`, `[`, `0`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `B`, `C` or `Q`,
- the rest is interpreted as listing a set of alternatives, specificially the character class mentioned above, *or* `Q[8-9]` *or * `C6` *or * `CE]`. That is why the `CE` doesn't work, because it does not have a square bracket with it.

What you are probably after is `(?:04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE)`

Comment: @ anyone who may care: [04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE] should be equivalent to [04CQ26B[2-6]+trailingJunkNotInTheCharacterClass (note that it collapses to a character *set* and ] is not protected at a random location internally)

Comment: A late thought: wouldn't the first `[` match the first `]`, so the character class would be `[04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]` leaving the next chunk to be interpreted as an alternation of `Q[8-9]` or `C6` or `CE]`.

Comment: @Tim: In Java regexes, the square brackets do "nest" - for example, `[B[2-6]Q[8-9]]` is the same as `[B2-6Q8-9]`.  This is not true of all regex flavors (it may be unique to Java for all I know).

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't make any sense:

```
[04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE]
```

I believe you want:

```
(?:04|C0|Q2|Q6|C4|B[2-6]|Q[8-9]|C6|CE)
```

Square brackets are only used for character classes, not general grouping. Use `(?:...)` or `(...)` for general grouping (the latter also captures).